# PHP GD only: PNG24+Alpha => PNG8 does not save Alpha

Tags: php, png, alpha-transparency, png-8

**Please do not post code which you have not actually tested!**
I have spent some time looking for this answer. There are several similar posts here on StackOverflow, but nothing I have found can produce this seemingly simple result.

[pngquant](http://pngquant.org/) is very nice for certain uses, but in this case, *I have a specific use which I am trying to fill, which means using only the generic PHP with GD install*.

Now the relevant code in its entirety! This simple code, produces a high color PNG image, with a translucent alpha channel. Works great, simple and effective!

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 65, 65, 65, 20);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $color);

header('content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img, 'test.png');
imagedestroy($img);

print file_get_contents('test.png');
?>
```

The following, nearly identical code, produces an 8bit PNG image file, unfortunately, the Alpha channel data is lost.

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 65, 65, 65, 20);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $color);
imagetruecolortopalette($img, false, 255); #this line missing in sample above
header('content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img, 'test.png');
imagedestroy($img);

print file_get_contents('test.png');
?>
```

Knowing that an 8bit PNG with alpha channel is demonstrably possible, can PHP GD do it, or not? It appears PHP GD is incapable, a bit of a turkey, but some of you are far more advanced than I am and may know the definitive answer one way or the other...

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call `imagesavealpha` after you did the palette conversion, so the new/converted palette is "adapted" with alpha values. This should work:

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50);

$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 65, 65, 65, 20);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $color);
imagetruecolortopalette($img, false, 255);

imagesavealpha($img, true);

header('content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img, 'test.png');
imagedestroy($img);

print file_get_contents('test.png');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, I just ran your code variant, no dice. Still comes out opaque.

Comment: Update the alpha value in `imagecolorallocatealpha` to 0. PNG8 does not support partial transparency. It's either opaque or it isn't.

Comment: This is a PNG8 with partial transparency:
http://tinypng.org/images/example-shrunk-8cadd4c7.png (fixed)

The question is not if partial transparency is possible in the PNG8 format, it is. The question is whether PHP GD is able to produce a PNG8 with partial transparency (opacity), a proper alpha channel.

Comment: @unidentified-1, I've learned something new today - thanks! Unfortunately I'm not familiar with PHP GD's support for it. Based on the discussion above, I suspect it doesn't. Link for the curious, [PNG8 supports variable transparency](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2010/08/do-you-care-about-png-8-with-transparency.html)